# $\int \frac{x}{2x^{12}-x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \frac{x}{2x^{12}-x^2+1}dx$

**My attempt:** Firstly, I say $u=x^2 \implies du=2xdx$ then integrant turns out to be $\frac {1}{2} \int \frac{du}{2u^6-u+1}$

But I couldn't continue.

Comment: Why do you assume that there is a simple answer?

Comment: One way to do it is factoring the denominator into its $6$ complex roots, then doing partial fractions and then integrating (all logarithms). I believe there is no simple closed form, and Wolfram seems to agree: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bx%2C2Power%5Bx%2C12%5D-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2B1%5D%2Cx%5D

Comment: Was this a definite integral? What were the bounds?

Answer (score 2):

Let $I=\int \frac{du}{P(u)}$ where $P(u)=u^n+\dots$ is a polynom of $n$-th degree without repeated roots and the leading term $u^n$; so
$$
P(u)=(u-u_1)(u-u_2)\dots(u-u_n)
$$
where $u_j$'s are distinct roots of the equation $P(u)=0$.
We can then write
$$
\frac1{P(u)}=\frac{1}{(u-u_1)(u-u_2)\dots(u-u_n)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{u-u_k}
$$
for some numbers $a_k\in\mathbb{C}$, and as a result,
$$
I=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \ln|u-u_k| +Const.
$$
To find the values of $a_j$s , note that
$$
\frac{1}{\prod_{k\ne j}(u-u_k)}= a_j+(u-u_j)\sum_{k=1,k\ne j}^n \frac{a_k}{u-u_k}
$$
and substituting $u=u_j$ we get
$$
a_j=\left(\prod_{k=1,k\ne j}^n(u_j-u_k)\right)^{-1}.
$$
Finally, in the identity
$$
\frac{P(u)}{u-u_j}=\prod_{k=1,k\ne j}^n(u-u_k)
$$
we can take the limit as $u\to u_j$ and using L'Hôpital's rule
on the left we get
$$
P'(u_j)=\prod_{k=1,k\ne j}^n(u_j-u_k)\equiv a_j^{-1}
$$
yielding
$$
I=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\ln|u-u_k|}{P'(u_k)} +Const.
$$
In your case, we can take $P(u)=u^6-u/2+1/2$, and since we cannot find the roots analytically, the answer is
\begin{align*}
I&\approx \left(0.179+0.058 i \right)\ln\left(x+0.835+ 0.536i \right) + \left(0.179-0.058i\right) \ln  \left( x+ 0.835- 0.536i \right) 
\\ &
+\left(0.142+ 0.220i \right)\ln\left(x- 0.125+ 0.919i \right)+\left(0.142-0.220i \right)\ln\left( x- 0.125- 0.919i\right)
\\ &
 - \left(  0.321-0.432i\right)\ln \left(x- 0.710+ 0.293i \right) - \left(  0.321+0.432i \right) \ln  \left( x- 0.710- 0.293i \right) 
\end{align*}

Note: to avoid dealing with logarithms of complex numbers, you can first combine the pairs of conjugate roots of $P$. For example, if $u_1,u_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ and $u_1=c+bi=\bar u_2$, then $a_2=\bar a_1$ ane
$$
\frac{a_1}{u-u_1}+\frac{a_2}{u-u_2}=\frac{2\ \mathrm{Re}(P'(u_1)(u-u_1))}{|P'(u_1)|^2 }\cdot \frac{1}{(u-c)^2+b^2}
$$
which will ultimately result in getting $\arctan$ after the integration.

In this particular case,
$$
\frac1{P(u)}\approx
\frac{0.7102110352- 0.6427701264u}{u^2- 1.420768730u+ 0.5907061898}+\frac{0.3695859117+ 0.2838525678u}{u^2-0.2493626114u+ 0.8592566099}+\frac{0.3620879957+0.3589175586u}{u^2+ 1.670131342u+ 0.9850892983}
$$
so
\begin{align*}
I&\approx - 0.3213850632\,\ln  \left( 5\,{u}^{2}- 7.103843650\,u+
 2.953530949 \right)
\\ &
+ 0.1794587793\,\ln\left( {u}^{2}+ 1.670131342\,u+ 0.9850892983 \right)
\\ &
+ 0.1419262839\,\ln  \left(u^2-0.2493626114\,u+ 0.8592566099 \right) 
\\ & + 0.8644565039\,\arctan\left(3.408777967\,u-2.421542571 \right) 
\\ &+ 0.1162659379\,\arctan\left(1.864184295\,u+ 1.556716309 \right) 
\\ &+ 0.4408932789\,\arctan \left(1.088687152\,u- 0.1357389356 \right)
+Const.
\end{align*}

Comment: Which combination of logs do you need to make it real valued when it should be? (Generally this consideration is a reason to recombine the conjugate pairs of roots into quadratics that are irreversible over $\mathbb{R}$ and get arctangents out of those terms.)

Comment: Well, I slightly cheated, you need actually first to combine conjugate roots; if $u_k=c+bi$ and say $u_{k+1}=c-bi$, then combining these two terms, you get $\frac{(P'(c+bi)')^{-1}}{u-(c+bi)}+\frac{(P'(c-bi)')^{-1}}{u-(c-bi)}=\frac{smth}{(u-c)^2+b^2}$ which will be real, as the sum of two conjugate terms, and the integration will result in the $\arctan$.